# Hibernate createNativeQuery - get more than one Entity

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I am using following code to execute native SQL query with hibernate:

```
    Query zonesQuery = session.createNativeQuery(
        "Select * \n" +
           "FROM dbo.Structure AS S\n" +
           "JOIN dbo.StructureLocationType AS SLT ON SLT.StructureId = S.Id\n" +
           "WHERE SLT.LocationTypeId = :lc").addEntity(StructureEntity.class);

zonesQuery.setParameter("lc", locationTypeID);
List<StructureEntity> zones = zonesQuery.list();
```

So it works and it gets me list of StructureEntity

now, because my sql query "join" from StructureLocationType table, is there possibility to get whole StructureLocationType row as well, still using single query?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't get multiple Objects from one query. But you could create a class which holds all the information you need and the compile it using joins in the query.

Comment: Hi @ChiffShinz - would you be able to provide any example of such solution, please? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get multiple Objects from one query.

But you could either select which columns you want and then iterate the returned Object array:

The query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.someColumn, slt.id, slt.structureId
FROM dbo.Structure AS s
JOIN dbo.StructureLocationType AS slt on slt.structureId = s.id
WHERE slt.locationTypeId = :lc
```

Then iterate over the Object array:

```
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
```

Or you could create a view on your database and map it to a java entity using the Table annotation like it was a normal table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STRUCTURE_LOCATION_TYPE_VIEW")
public class StructureAndLocationType {
    // ...
}
```

I thought there is a way to map from a query to an Object without creating a DB view but couldn't find it right now.

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved with the following (notice curly braces in SQL and entities aliases):

```java
Query query = session
   .createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT {S.*}, {SLT.*} " +
        "FROM dbo.Structure AS S " +
        "JOIN dbo.StructureLocationType AS SLT ON SLT.StructureId = S.Id " +
        "WHERE SLT.LocationTypeId = :lc")
   .unwrap(SQLQuery.class)
   .addEntity("S", StructureEntity.class)
   .addEntity("SLT", StructureLocationTypeEntity.class)
   .setParameter("lc", locationTypeID);


List<Pair<StructureEntity, StructureLocationTypeEntity>> result = ((List<Object[]>) query.list())
    .stream()
    .map(p -> Pair.of((StructureEntity) p[0], (StructureLocationTypeEntity) p[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```